# Date value changes when copied

Tags: excel, vba

I have cells containing a simple concatenation function with D24 as the previous year (e.g. 15) and a custom format (**MMM JJ**)

`CONCATENATE("Apr ",$D$24)`

When I am copying and pasting these cells with a VBA then "Apr 15" becomes "15.04.16" and because of the formatting "Apr 16"

`Selection.Value = Selection.Value`

Was is the reason behind this? Is there another solution than just changing the format to text?

Answer (score 2):

Excel will generally try to convert anything that looks like a date into a real date (serial number where 1 = 1 Jan 1900).  One way to avoid that, and remove the formula as you are doing above, would be to pre-format as text.  So:

```
With Selection
    .NumberFormat = "@"
    .Value = .Text
End With
```

might do what you want.

There are other ways, but if you don't change the cell format to text, or prefix the entry with a single quote `'`, any subsequent editing of that cell, even inadvertent selection, raises the risk of converting it to the real date.

Answer (score 2):

That depends on what you want in your cell. Dou you want a string or a date?

If you want a string:

- either format as text or
- add a ': `CONCATENATE("'Apr ",$D$24)`

if you want a date:

- use the following formula instead of concatenate: `=DATE($D$24,4,1)`

Answer (score 0):

If you simply Copy Paste it, only the Value is pasted not the formatting (if I remember right)

Try to [avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) using `Selection` instead use `Range`.

And use `Range.Copy` and `Range.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats` so your formatting is pasted with the values.

Comment: `xlPasteAll` will copy the formula also; whereas the code in the OP removes the formula.  Try pasting just the values.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the question. In that case you could us xlPasteFormats. Edited my original commen.

Comment: It may have been me who misunderstood, or the OP may not have explained clearly what he wanted to do.  But don't forget to also copy over the value; and test to see what you get when you use your method.

Comment: With `Selection.Value = Selection.Value` you are pasting the values in the same cells where the formula was. Therefore, the formatting is the same and, furthermore, you can by-pass the clipboard with this method